# Batch File error

Tags: file, batch-file

When I run the following batch file it show me an error that "The directory name is invalid." The .exe file of notepad and others actually are inside System32 folder. I am not sure how to write the path:

```
@echo off
CLS
:Menu
ECHO.

ECHO...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 to select your task; or 3 to exit
ECHO...............................................
EcHO.

ECHO 1 - OPEN NOTEPAD
ECHO 2 - OPEN WRITE
ECHO 3 - OPEN EXIT
ECHO.

SET /p M=Type 1,2, or 3 then press enter:
IF %M% == 1 GOTO NOTEPAD
IF %M% == 2 GOTO WRITE
IF %M% == 3 GOTO EOF
:NOTEPAD
cd %windir%\notepad.exe
start notepad.exe
GOTO MENU
:WRITE
cd %windir%\write.exe
start write.exe
GOTO MENU
```

Thanks
Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `cd` to a file, just a directory. Since these are in the System32 folder, they're already in the system path so you don't even need to cd to that directory.

```
@echo off
CLS
:Menu
ECHO.

ECHO...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 to select your task; or 3 to exit
ECHO...............................................
EcHO.

ECHO 1 - OPEN NOTEPAD
ECHO 2 - OPEN WRITE
ECHO 3 - OPEN EXIT
ECHO.

SET /p M=Type 1,2, or 3 then press enter:
IF %M% == 1 GOTO NOTEPAD
IF %M% == 2 GOTO WRITE
IF %M% == 3 GOTO EOF
:NOTEPAD
start notepad.exe
GOTO MENU
:WRITE
start write.exe
GOTO MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make things confusing, you can use the following commands:

```
@echo off
CLS
set %mydir%=C:\Windows\System32
:Menu
ECHO.
ECHO...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 to select your task; or 3 to exit
ECHO...............................................
EcHO.

ECHO 1 - OPEN NOTEPAD
ECHO 2 - OPEN WRITE
ECHO 3 - OPEN EXIT
ECHO.

SET /p M=Type 1,2, or 3 then press enter:
IF %M% == 1 GOTO NOTEPAD
IF %M% == 2 GOTO WRITE
IF %M% == 3 GOTO EOF
:NOTEPAD
start %mydir%\notepad.exe
GOTO MENU
:WRITE
start %mydir%\write.exe
GOTO MENU
:EOF
PAUSE
EXIT
```

One other problem I noted is that you do not have an :EOF script.... Does this work?

Comment: `:eof` is a "built-in-label"`(End Of File). `goto :eof` always jumps to the very end of the script (which effectily means: stop the script). `goto eof` on the other hand will refer to a label (note the use / non-use of `:`)

Comment: OK. My mistake, sorry about that. Also, if my questions are helpful please up vote them to improve my reputation. Thanks!